# Numerically stable computation of logarithm of sum and fraction of exponentials

Tags: logarithms, exponentiation, numerical-calculus

I am trying to compute the following expression numerically stable:

$$ \log \left(\frac{5 e^{a+b}+3 e^a+3 e^b-3}{-e^{a+b}+e^a+e^b+7}\right) \text{ for }a,b\in\mathbb{R} $$

I have attempted simplifying it but found nothing solving the problem of having to evaluate an exponential, sum up, and then evaluating the logarithm.

Comment: The logsumexp trick might be related to your problem. http://gregorygundersen.com/blog/2020/02/09/log-sum-exp/

Comment: @Serge Thanks, I know, but I was not able to make it numerically more stable already because of the $e^{a+b}$ term.